# Process images in real time Android

Tags: android, image, process, camera

I am doing an Android app to process images in real time, and I don't know which is the most efficiently way to process these frames.

I launch acquisition process in a thread like this:

```
/**
     * Thread to open camera acquisition process
     */
    private static class CameraHandlerThread extends HandlerThread {
        Handler mHandler = null;

        CameraHandlerThread() {
            super("CameraHandlerThread");
            start();
            mHandler = new Handler(getLooper());
        }

        synchronized void notifyCameraOpened() {
            notify();
        }

        void openCamera() {
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        mCamera = Camera.open(cameraUsed.ordinal());
                    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "failed to open front camera");
                    }
                    notifyCameraOpened();
                }
            });
            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.w(TAG, "wait was interrupted");
            }
        }
    }
```

I reach high frame rates (25 fps more and less) and my process task are about 300 ms. Which is the best and the fastest way to launch these tasks? In other thread? In main thread?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are following things that you should keep in mind

1. the number of processors on your android device
2. amount of RAM available

the most efficient would be when

```
number of threads == number of processors
```

but the more the threads the more the RAM required.

So you should decide depending on available RAM and CPUs.

btw, Camera.open is a blocking call, so put it in a thread, that's more efficient, but I hope you're not processing images under Camera.open, because in that case, threads or no threads doesn't matter.